# filtering in angular by select and checkbox

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

want to filter out values both the select box and in checkbox i achieved in select box but can't able to get from checkbox

[MY PLUNKER DEMO](https://embed.plnkr.co/cugcxkUnvtamdkkTM7WL/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Example Here](https://plnkr.co/edit/xdO1hK64ZLIGX89ViyTB?p=preview). Use a single object for the checkboxes, and then you can use a comparator function in the filter, like this:

```
$scope.checkMake = function(value) {

  //Assume no filter is applied so the value will be shown.
  var result = true;

  for (var i in $scope.selected) {
      if ($scope.selected[i] === true) {
          //if we get here, we know a filter is applied, so 
          //check to see if the passed value is one of the selected 
          //checkboxes
          result = $scope.selected[value];
          break;
      }
  }
  return result;
}
```